# How to read the call log on iPhone iOS 5 programmatically 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I found many code samples for reading the call log on iOS 4, but it seems that this feature (reading the call log DB) is not enabled on iOS 5.

So what is the work-around? Is there any (third party?) method or trick to be able to read the call log in iOS 5?

Comment: I sure hope that there isn't. The fact that that information was exposed in iOS 4 seems more like a bug than a feature, especially considering that there was never any API for it.

Comment: Expect that sort of information to get locked down as Appe increases user privacy

Comment: I don't understand why Apple won't allow users to grant access like they do with GPS location.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [SpyPhone](https://github.com/nst/SpyPhone) project on GitHub.

For example, you can get the most recently dialed number like so:

```
NSString *path = @"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mobilephone.plist";
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *lastDialed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [d valueForKey:@"DialerSavedNumber"]];
```

This works on my iOS5 phone. I would not expect Apple to be happy with this sort of functionality anymore.

Comment: Thanks, that seems cool
But I still cant find a way to query to call log, to get "Dialed number, Duration, Incoming/Outgoing ... etc"

Comment: Hey Do you have any idea that from ios 8 we can get All call logs detail ?