# Read Call History from iPhone on iOS 5 and above

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios4

I am developing an application and need to read the users call history from iPhone.I have go though all the forums and google it and found that we can get the records from teh callHistory sqlite database by "private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db". But this path is not working from iOS 5 and above. Seems like apple has changed all their database path and structure so that no one can accees it.

I have also seen some of the application on iTunes who are capable of getting the users call history like:-https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/callog/id327883585?mt=8

I have also check a mac desktop utility called "WonderShare Dr.Fone"  which will fetch all the data from your iPhone like call history messages, notes , etc.How this utility is fetching the call history records and other details?

If their is any API or private APIs by which i can get  the  callHistory data path please let me know.

Comment: Did you read how the app you link to works?.

Comment: Yes i have check the callLog. They are accessing the private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db to get the callHistory records. but that path is not avialable from iOs5 and above.

Comment: **take a look** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057395/how-to-read-the-call-log-on-iphone-ios-5-programmatically

Comment: WonderShare...  It's no personal, but that's not a very good name to mention.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the call log using the SDK and approved APIs however `callLog` is still a Mystery. That thing only works with iOS 4. Now, Apple have restricted some area in iPhone disk and we can't get anything from that area.

Check this **Tutorial :** [Accessing iPhone Call History](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)

**Note :** It works only with iOS 4.

Comment: Thanks Vin. I have already checked that CallHistory records . I think they are not in business yet.But i have seen iExplorer utility for mac which will  fetch all the iPhone data like call records , notes. etc. How that utility is working at backend?

Comment: @SandeepDhama: Mystery Continues... :)

Comment: If you got any possible solution for this question than please share your answer here. Many Thanks